# Have the top two teams in the NHL ever met in the Stanley Cup Finals?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

For example, the Stars and the Caps for this year.

Edit:

This is modern era, where we've had full 4-tier playoffs.

Comment: Did you want to write "two top teams" instead of "to two teams"?

Comment: You should also clarify in your question whether you mean Stanley Cup finals or Stanley Cup playoffs.

Comment: What about Montreal - Calgary in [1988-89 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988%E2%80%9389_NHL_season)? And Edmonton-Philadelphia in [1986-87 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986%E2%80%9387_NHL_season)? Wikipedia has list of [President Trophy winners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidents%27_Trophy#Winners) and their playoff results - you can check there which team they played in the playoffs.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Please define more specifically when "the modern era" starts; also do you mean the top two teams league-wide (which might be in the same conference, who could obviously never meet in the Finals) or the top team from each conference?

Comment: I did.  "where we've had full 4-tier playoffs.  It seems less likely in the scenario where there are at least 16 teams.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The NHL spent 25 years with only six teams (the "Original Six" era), and to some extent only three of those teams were competitive, so this has happened many times.

Going even further back (to the 1920s), the playoffs were just a matchup between the top two teams, so this was guaranteed to happen.